# Sort an NSDictionary (which contains my Facebook friends list)

Tags: iphone, sorting, facebook-graph-api, nsarray, nsdictionary

Using the Graph Facebook API with this code

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
```

Now I have an NSDictionary which is like this:

```
{data =     (
            {
        id = 123456;
        name = "Mark Zuckerberg";
    },
            {
        id = 654321;
        name = "Steve Jobs";
    },
            {
        id = 13579;
        name = "Bill Gates";
    }
    ...
  );
}
```

I want to sort this NSDictionary, but I know that is not possible.
Of course, I can create 2 NSArray (or NSMutableArray), one "array_id" and the other one "array_name".
I'd like to sort "array_name", but keeping the reference to the id.

For example, if my two arrays are something like this:

```
array_name = {"Mark", "Steve", "Bill};
array_id   = {"123456", "654321", "13579"};
```

I want, at the end, something like this:

```
array_name = {"Bill", "Mark", "Steve"};
array_id   = {"13579", "123456", "654321"};
```

What do you suggest me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you want to sort an `NSDictionary`, you want to sort an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` objects that just so happens to itself be in an `NSDictionary`. You can simply extract this friends array as follows:

```
NSArray *unsortedFriends = [dictionaryFromFacebook objectForKey:@"data"];
```

Now you can do the following:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedFriends = [unsortedFriends sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` method of NSArray. The comparator block would return the result of comparing the names of its arguments.

```
NSDictionary *requestResult = ...; // get your original dictionary
NSArray *unsortedArray = [requestResult objectForKey:@"data"];
NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSString *name1 = (NSString *)[(NSDictionary *)obj1 objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *name2 = (NSString *)[(NSDictionary *)obj2 objectForKey:@"name"];
    return [name1 caseInsensitiveCompare:name2];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple thing would be to create a new kind of object:

```
@interface Friend : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *facebookID;

@end

@implementation Friend

@synthesize name, facebookID;

- (void)dealloc {
  [name release];
  [facebookID release];
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

When you have this, you can loop through your array that you got back and do:

```
NSMutableArray *friends = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *rawFriend in arrayOfFriends) {
  NSString *name = [rawFriend objectForKey:@"name"];
  NSString *fID = [rawFriend objectForKey:@"id"];

  if (name && fID) {
    Friend *f = [[Friend alloc] init];
    [f setName:name];
    [f setFacebookID:fID];
    [friends addObject:f];
    [f release];
  }
}
```

Once you've done that, it's simple to sort things:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[friends sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName]];
```

Comment: Hi Dave, why would you go to the effort of creating a `Friend` class when KVC methods work on `NSDictionary` objects that have string keys?

Comment: @Sedate Alien it's cleaner. It's also far more future-proof.

Comment: Fair enough; I guess you may want to extend the Friend class in the future and that would be better than a hotchpotch of dictionaries where a genuine object would be more appropriate. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the 3 methods [`-keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [`-keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html), or [`-keysSortedByValueWithOptions:usingComparator:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get an array of the keys sorted in order.  So, if you want to iterate in order, you can do something like this:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = ...;
for (id key in [myDict keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)])
{
    id value = [myDict objectForKey:key];
    // Do stuff with (key, value)
}
```

If you need a separate array containing all of the values in the order corresponding to the sorted order of the keys, then do the above iteration and construct that array.